# Should I send login id on email?

Tags: authentication, email, account-security

I have a very common use case where an admin is creating an account of the user and then I need to send the login id generated by my system to the user. And the user will need to set a password on the first login.

So my question here is should I send the user id on email and if yes, then what are the security risks that must need to be incorporated?

Comment: are you the admin creating the account?what is the procedure for setting up the first password?

Comment: The procedure I thought is that when admin creates an account then he will add user's phone no also. So when user will try to log in first time using his login id then he will receive an OTP on his phone and after entering the OTP he can set his password.

Comment: Please write the complete procedure and explain to me why an admin is creating other users account and where does he get users mobile numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login ID should be considered public. So feel free to send it per email.